# Plus / Minus Toggle Instead of Text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been developing a menu for the past few days.  It will serve as a expandable / collapsible (is that even a word?) menu.  Right now I got the menu to be bigger vertically by default, then when you click the "+/-" button, the size decreases vertically. You click it again, then it gets bigger vertically.. etc.

Here is the JQuery part:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.gh-gallink').toggle(function() {
        $('.gallery_container').animate({
            marginTop: "-60px",
            paddingTop: "75px",
            paddingBottom: "0px",
            height: "36px"
        }, 1000)
    }, function() {
        $('.gallery_container').animate({
            marginTop: "0px",
            paddingTop: "40px",
            paddingBottom: "0px",
            height: "100px"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Here is the html for the toggle button:

```
< p class = "gallerylink" >
< a href="#" class="gh-gallink" title="Expand / Collapse Menu" >
    + / -
< /a >
< /p >
```

So right now, everything works great. The menu functions correctly and when you click "+/-" it either gets smaller vertically, or larger vertically.  But, I would like the menu to show a "-" by deafult (since the menu is large by default). And then when you click the - sign and it gets smaller, I would like there to be a "+". A fadein / fade out transition would be awesome as well.

Any help would be deeply appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're directly changing the size with `animate()` simply chain the `text()` method following the `animate()` and explicitly define:

```
/* ...the animate stuff to make smaller...*/});
$(this).text('+');

/* ...the animate stuff to make larger...*/});
$(this).text('-');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RC9fU/1/).

Comment: I tried your 1st method, here is what I did:
$(window).load(function(){
$('.gh-gallink').toggle(
  function() {
    $('.gallery_container').animate({ marginTop: "-60px",  paddingTop: "75px", paddingBottom: "0px", height: "36px"  }, 1000) 
  },
  function() {
    $('.gallery_container').animate({ marginTop: "0px", paddingTop: "40px", paddingBottom: "0px", height: "100px" }, 1000);
  },
  function() {
     $('.gh-gallink').text(function(i,t){ return t == '-' ? '+' : '-'; });
  }    
);

}); 

It just added the plus sign once I clicked +/- a few times. Then a - sign once I clicked plus twice. :(

Comment: [*Show*, don't tell](http://jsfiddle.net/) (but, obviously, describe). Also for large code segments edit it into the question (and explain why it's there). Anyway, show me what you've got going on (just a representative/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demo).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help man.  Here is my menu: http://jsfiddle.net/RC9fU/ with your code entered into the JS Section.  Click the toggle plus minus button a few times and see what happens.

Comment: You're welcome, I removed the (erstwhile) first option (since there's no real need for a conditional assessment), and just used the second (explicit) options: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RC9fU/1/).

Comment: Awesome man thankks so much! (Just checked the updated code). Works like a charm. :)

Comment: You're *absolutely* welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: Sorry to bug you (again!).  But the code doesn't work when its in the header. Or on JSFiddle, when its set to no wrap (head).  Is there any way to get it to work so the JS loads in the header?  Or is it just impossible?

Comment: You're using jQuery. Use `$(document).ready(/* all your stuff in here */);`. Or `$(window).load(/* all your stuff in here */);`. So long as you're including the jQuery library you should be set.